# Error hint after submit when using input fields in a popup

Tags: javascript, jsf, popup, facelets

we've been looking for a working implementation in JSF 1.2 & Facelets where it is possible to get an error hint (e.g. invalid date) after submitting a form which is partly or completely filled in a popup. E.g. you fill in some data, click on a link which opens a popup, enter more data, close popup and submit. At the moment our realization is just blocking after one is submitting the page and we get no error message directing the user to e.g. an invalid date in the popup. Is there already something out there which addresses this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally did it with prototype in javascript. E.g. add Javascript to your tag which looks for error_fields class in the innerHTML elements and then somehow activates the corresponding popup. This is done after onDomContentLoaded event.
Feel free to ask for code if you are interested. Other solutions would still be interesting.